# How can I loop the radio button through an array

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-flexi-radio-button (https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-flexi-radio-button) but I want to loop the radio buttons using the json values and its not working. Have a look at the code below. Thanks in advance

This works

```
<RadioGroup
  onSelect={(index, value) => this.onSelect(index, value)}>

  <RadioButton value={"item1"}>
    <Text>This is item #1</Text>
  </RadioButton>

</RadioGroup>
```

But the following gives cannot read property 'props' of null

```
<RadioGroup
  onSelect={(index, value) => this.onSelect(index, value)}
>
  {this.state.cuisinesByFoodList.map(item1 => {
    console.log("result", item1);
    <RadioButton value={"abc"}>
      <Text>{"abc"}</Text>
    </RadioButton>;
  })}
</RadioGroup>

P.S there's value in item1 in the console when debugged.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the items.

```
<RadioGroup
  onSelect={(index, value) => this.onSelect(index, value)}
>
  {this.state.cuisinesByFoodList.map(item1 => {
    console.log("result", item1);
    return(<RadioButton value={"abc"}>
      <Text>{"abc"}</Text>
    </RadioButton>);
  })}
</RadioGroup>
```